# R markdown - is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

Tags: r, r-markdown

[image]I was in the middle of making an R markdown document when all my code chunks started returning the same error "is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file." What's going on here?

example:

"""

``{test}

2 + 2

``

'test' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

"""

I opened a separate R markdown I had made previously and had no issues running any chunks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're missing the `r` at the start of the code chunk definition. Each code chunk should always start with three backticks then `r` and then the label.

e.g.

````
```{r test}

2 + 2

```
````

Comment: sigh... that's the one. Thank you

Comment: It's also not recommended to use underscores in chunk labels (use hyphens instead because underscores can sometimes cause issues)

Comment: I will implement those changes! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Cannot comment, but I highly recommend you provide more information, like the error, some image or even the entire code. Anyways, what seems more probably to me, if your others instances are working well, is that you accidentally deleted the opening or closening of one of your chunks, ``` those things.

In another issues related, it also could be a problem with the LaTeX version installed or even not having the "markdown" package, but in your case your other instances are working.